# how to avoid shared variable in Vue's mixin

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

Having mixin like

```
var MyMixin = {
  methods: {
    setupWebsocket: function (wsPath) {
      …
      Vue.use(
        VueNativeSock.default, url,
        {
          reconnection: true,
          reconnectionAttempts: 5,
          reconnectionDelay: 3000,
          format: 'json',
        }
      );

      this.$socket.onmessage = this.listen;
      this.$socket.onopen = this.onOpen;
}
```

Both `onOpen` and `listen` are defined in two different vue’s instances working together on same page and having own `onOpen` and `onmessage` each one:

```
var myApp1 = new Vue({
   …
   mixin: [MyMixin],
   created: function () {
    this.setupWebsocket(this.wsPath);
   },
   methods: {
     onOpen: function(){...},
     …
   }
```

The problem is `$socket` is shared and both instances will receive same `onOpen` and `listen` coming from the second instance (created later). I need a custom `onopen` in every instance.

Comment: Do they do the same thing? if they do just put a conditional on whatever loads first and don't initialize it if it exists.   
also this apparently THE use case for the new functional/composition api which is available via plugin in vue 2 (react-hooks style)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve it this way:

Moving `Vue.use` outside of the mixin and run it before creating any instance

```
function setupWebSocket(wsPath){
  var port = window.location.port;
  var domain = window.location.hostname + (port ? ':' + port : '');
  var schema = (port ? 'ws' : 'wss') + '://';
  var url = schema + domain + '/stream/' + wsPath;
  Vue.use(
    VueNativeSock.default, url,
    {
      reconnection: true,
      reconnectionAttempts: 5,
      reconnectionDelay: 3000,
      format: 'json',
    }
  );
}
...
setupWebSocket(wsPath);  // plain javascript outside component
```

Above gave me in every vue's instance access to

```
 instance.$options.sockets
```

which is a `Proxy`. (`$options.sockets` was unavailable before)

Then in `created` of instances I am able to set up custom functions for every component:

```
 instance.$options.sockets.onmessage

 instance.$options.sockets.onopen
```

Final test:

```
myApp1.$options == myAppB.$options
false
myApp1.$options.sockets == myAppB.$options.sockets
false
myApp1.$socket == myAppB.$socket
true
```

and now each instance runs its own custom `onopen`